# Как Java работает с UART в Android?

Tags: java, android, linux, uart

Вопрос чисто теоретический.

В Android есть SerialPort API в Java, которое позволяет работать с UART. И тут у меня один вопрос: вот как Java работает с UART "в обход" ядра?

Смотрите, в чем проблема. Пусть даже это Java машина, вследствие чего она имеет значительные привилегии в системе, но вся поддержка внешних устройств упирается в ядро Linux. В `/proc/config.gz` я не нашёл строк на CP2102, RS232 или UART, а даже то, что нашёл подходящего, было в NO. Т е, в ядре нету (?) поддержки Serial USB.

Когда я подключаю CP2102 переходник в ПК, у меня там появляется `/dev/ttyACM0`, к которому я могу подключиться. На Android такого устройства не появляется. Зато с ним я могу работать из необходимых приложений.

Вот реально парадокс: как вообще так получилось, что zygote работает с ttyACM0 на будь здоров, а вот собственно система вообще молчит, будто и не поддерживает вовсе этот ваш Serial. Если даже в ядре есть поддержка Serial (а она должна быть, иначе я вообще не понимаю, что за чертовщина творится в Android), то почему она не работает так штатно, как в обычном Linux, и как zygote все-таки получает доступ к устройству Serial USB? Что-что, а Android на уровне *базовой системы и ядра* - это все-таки Linux...

Comment: Вопрос я не понял. Но если я его понял правильно, то копать надо в сторону JNI. У Android  свои  нативные  вызовы и свой native jdk.  Не  уверен  насчет UART. но устройства  через JNI  доступны.

Comment: странно, что именно вы не поняли? zygote (Java машина Android) умеет работать с USB UART. В свою очередь, из консоли Android ты до UART не достучишься никак, будто в ядре нет его поддержки. Но ведь zygote - это userspace процесс, а значит, поддержка внешних устройств упирается в ядро. А раз zygote может работать с UART, то его поддержка должна быть в ядре. Но при подключении CP2102 Android не обнаруживает это устройство так, как Linux. В штатном дистрибутиве появляется устройство `/dev/ttyACM0`, в Android - нет, из-за чего с ним нельзя работать из shell скриптов

Comment: Zygote это  заручик  Davlik. Вы что пытиаетесь  мне доказать, что из загручика нельзя  обратиться  к UART?  я  все  рано не понял в чем  проблема? В  NDK  документацию  обращались?

Comment: наоборот, я не понимаю, почему Android приложение может обратиться к UART, а вот через Linux-овую консоль с UART не по работаешь

Comment: Почитай про `libusb` и драйверы в user space. И вообще, Android — это совсем не Linux с т.з. пользователя.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Узнал (причём не так уж и давно) про userspace драйвера, точнее - "uio". Пара устройств `/dev/uio` есть в моём телефоне, походу это они отвечают за UART.