# Как правильно читать исходный код?

Tags: теория

Вопрос общепрактического характера. Как правильно читать исходные коды, особенно тех программ, чей код длинный, сложный, разбит на несколько (даже десятков) файлов, с кучей объявлений (в т ч extern), с классами, namespace-ами и т д?

Просто мне, как человеку, сильно любящему углубляться в устройство Android (даже в штатный Linux я так сильно не погружался, просто в силу его большей понятности и простоты устройства (для меня по крайней мере)), не раз приходилось пытаться читать исходные коды. Цель, конечно, простая как сложение 2х 2ек - понять принцип работы тех или иных функций, библиотек, программ. Только из недавнего: [Как Java работает с UART в Android?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1440317/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-java-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%81-uart-%d0%b2-android). И разумеется, перед тем, как задавать подобные вопросы, я пытаюсь читать исходные коды программ, библиотек.

Но в том и проблема. Что в Magisk, что в python3-selinux, невзирая на неслабые знания и, какой-никакой, но опыт программирования на обоих языках (C++ и python соответственно), я просто ломаю голову, пытаясь досконально понять, что делает та или иная функция.

Но ключевое слово - **досконально**. Понятно, что основную информацию можно понять банально из названия файлов кода, названий функций, классов, namespace-ов. Но мне недостаточно, условно говоря, пояснения типа "парсит SELinux политику". У меня вопрос: "хорошо, а как именно это происходит? Как устроен формат sepolicy? Как он разбирается, что значат его байты, символы? Как именно политика пересобирается, как получается информация о контекстах?"

Но это не вопрос из разряда "как быть с слишком сложными вопросами". Здесь я задаю четкий вопрос: как правильно читать исходный код?

Не знаю, может это у меня одного такая проблема, но при чтении исходного кода легко запутаться, если он в нескольких файлах, использует ООП (классы, namespace, т п). При своих, пусть скромных, но каких-никаких знаниях, мне очень трудно читать исходный код.

Хотелось бы выслушать тех, кому это даётся +- хорошо. Может, есть инструменты, облегчающие чтение кода, есть какие-то техники, методы. Может есть статьи или даже литература по теме... Может, что-то по этому вопросу посоветуете...

Comment: Обязательно найдите себе *"проводника"*, который хотя бы вчерне познакомит вас с архитектурой и основополагающими принципами. Сэкономите себе кучу времени.

Comment: Это явно проблема XY. По факту вы не понимаете, как разобраться в назначении и работе того или иного компонента, а спрашиваете, как правильно читать исходные коды.

Comment: Многие темы описаны в RFC-ях... (правда, понять их может быть тоже не просто -)). Главное -- вытащить где-то из глубин интернета первооснову, т.е. понять мотивацию --  в чем именно состоит проблема, которая потом формально решается RFC и практически кодом. (Поняв, для чего именно нужен код, его уже начинаешь сам в голове проектировать и далее понимаешь, как это делал другой человек)

Answer (score 4):

Никак, Ваше желание разобраться в коде бесполезно без документов по этому  коду. Даже если Вы предположили, что поняли правильно написанное в коде, это не значит что вы правы. Инструментов по улучшению кода, выявлению проблем в коде, много. Инструментов объясняющих код нет. Только документация и только общение с автором кода. При этом, через два дня, сам автор уже не знает зачем он использовал ту конструкцию, а не эту и почему переменная названа - "Инкрементальное увеличение интового значения в цикле", а не "i".

Кроме этого не забывайте о локальных, принятых в Компаниях, правилах оформления кода. Человек работающий у нас сначала знакомиться с правилами оформления кода, потом тренируется писать код как принято у нас и только потом пишет код.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос довольно холиварный. Но всё же отвечу, хотя и несколько предвзято. На мой взгляд для чтения хорошо написанного кода не требуются никакие особые способности. А вот для чтения плохо написанного кода нужно ухищряться, но проблема в том, что плохой код может быть написан самыми разнообразными способами (в отличие от хорошего кода). Вам придётся учить шаблоны плохого проектирования, чтобы хорошо читать плохой код. Оно вам надо?

Хороший код:

- самодокументированный
- короткий (правильно отрефакторенный)
- понятный
- правильно использует ООП

Например (условный питоноподобный язык):

```
разгребание_очереди(очередь):
    вывод("начинаю разгребать")
    если очередь.не_пустая():
        элемент = очередь.взять()
        обработка_элемента(элемент)
    иначе:
        вывод("разгребание закончено")

класс очередь:
    ...

    не_пустая():
        ...

    взять():
        ...

обработка_элемента(элемент):
    ...
```

В хорошо отрефакторенном коде на каждом из уровней абстракции всё должно быть довольно понятно просто даже из названий классов, методов и переменных. Код должен быть короткий. Хотите разобраться детальнее - смотрите вызываемые функции, опускаетесь глубже от абстракций к конкретике. Для понимания сути происходящего всегда должно быть достаточно и текущего уровня абстракции. Но при необходимости можно и детали посмотреть на любую нужную глубину.

Comment: *"В хорошо отрефакторенном коде на каждом из уровней абстракции всё должно быть довольно понятно"* - ага, вы бы еще упомянули полноценную документацию и подробные примеры...

Comment: Я видел код  якобы написанный в стиле Domain design (Все обьекты имеют название предметной области), так вот без знания предметной области ничего не было понятно. А что бы узнать  предметную область необходимо отучитьяс миниму 5 лет в институте.

Comment: @Труфальдино Так без знания предметной области вы скорее всего и сути происходящего с этими переменными всё-равно не поймёте :)

Comment: @CrazyElf так об этом и разговор.  Мало того что надо быть кодером пищущем понятный код, надо  еще понимать о чем пишешь код. А учитывая заданный вопрос,  делам  вывод- без подготовки в предметной области читать код бесполезно.

Comment: CrazyElf, в том и дело, что из названий классов и функций-то примерно можно понять, а я, как уже говорил в своём вопросе, хочу углубляться и изучать досконально, до мелочей...